# How to get a correct README when using a dtx file

Tags: dtx

I use Joseph Wright's [model dtx file](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/). Unfortunately, when using it, the generated README.txt file contains parts of the package code, which is of course unwanted.

The rather long minimal example is appended at the end. The important part regarding my question is quite on the top, where only "Text" should end up in the README.txt to my understanding:

```
%<*readme>
Text
%</readme>
```

Instead, the README.txt looks like

```
Text
\endbatchfile
\def\shouldNotBeInReadme{really}
```

Why is that? What did I do wrong?

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
Text
%</readme>
%<readme>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
\expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
Preamble
\endpreamble
\postamble
Postamble
\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/tikzscale}
\generate{
\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/tikzscale}
\generate{
\file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/tikzscale}
\generate{
\file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
\expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
\expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{tikzscale}[2012/09/10 v0.1 tikzscale LaTeX package]
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
%\title{Title}
%\author{Author}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v0.1}{2012/09/10}{First public release}
%
% Text
\def\shouldNotBeInReadme{really}
%
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%^^A  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%\Finale
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an 'unguarded' code line. If you have a line in the `.dtx` which does not start `%` and is 'outside' of the guards, it appears in *every* extracted file. You can see that if you look in the `.sty` or `.ins` files. So you want

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\def\shouldNotBeInReadme{really}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
```

or

```
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\shouldNotBeInReadme{really}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
```

or similar.

Not linked to the issue, but the line

```
%<readme>\endbatchfile
```

is also spurious.

Comment: if you're thinking of distributing via ctan, please note that ctan needs `README`, not `README.txt` -- renaming it slows us down, so please try to remember that the `.txt` bit is a mistake.  (my apologies if you weren't intending that the package be submitted to ctan.)

Comment: @wasteofspace It's not possible to get DocStrip to create a file with no extension: TeX will not do this. So the best that can be done in the `.dtx` is to use a sensible extension. (In the build scripts I've also discussed on my blog, I think I've mentioned something similar and include a rename part.)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the great answer, for the additional information and for the original code. I added a hardlink to README.txt with name README. The latter one is now used in my ctanify script. That might be a good compromise, given the constraints you mentioned here and on your blog.

Comment: @wasteofspace Thanks a lot for mentioning, I'd had overseen this issue otherwise, as the plan is to distribute this package via ctan one day.

Comment: @JosephWright If I use the command `\generate{\file{README.}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}}` with a period after `README` I get the file without an extension.  Is this a change from your comment above?

Comment: @BillN No, you'll get a file called `README.` with a full stop in it: that's _not_ the same as `README` with no extention at all. Notably, CTAN now accept files called `README.md` (MarkDown) which would probably be the easiest approach to take.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, but there's something odd here. When I `ls` from Linux or `dir` from Windows in the directory with that file I get `README`, not `README.` I generated the file from a TeXLive setup on a Windows machine.  At the bottom line, I guess I'll use the `.md` extension just to be sure.

Comment: Before I push an update to CTAN, I use a shell script to (in addition to several other things) rename my `README.txt` file to `README` and that works just fine. I may begin using `README.md` with my next update.